# Button onclick shows id and value undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am dynamically adding buttons to my page, then `onclick` I want to get the `id` or `value` but it shows `undefined`. Here is my code:

```
for(i=1; i<=jj; i++){
  $("#buttonPanel").append('<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-top:20px; width: 40px;" id="'+i+'" value="'+i+'" onclick="btnpanel()"/>'+'&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp');
}
```

And here’s the jQuery code for the event listener:

```
function btnpanel(){
  alert($(this).attr("id"));
  alert($(this).attr("value"));
}
```

Comment: You have to pass `this` to inline onclick function callback. Or better, use delegation to bind event. That's said, simply checking inside handler what is `this`(window!) would show you why your code doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did:

```
for (i = 1; i <= jj; i++) {
    $("#buttonPanel").append('<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-top:20px; width: 40px;" id="' + i + '" value="' + i + '" />' + '&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp');
}

$("#buttonPanel").on("click", ".btn", function () {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
    alert($(this).attr("value"));
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x0tsrgsL/1/)

Comment: You have to remove inline `onclick` attribute then

Comment: I have now removed the inline onclick :)

Answer (score 1):

In case you would want to have a no jQuery solution and wish to use onclick handler,

pass `this` in `onclick="btnpanel()"` as `onclick="btnpanel(this)"`.

Your btnpanel function would look like,

```
function btnpanel(obj){
    alert(obj.id);
    alert(obj.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Delegate event to container element and get rid of `onclick` attribute:

```
$(function(){
    $("#buttonPanel").on('click', '.btn', function(){
        alert(this.id);
        alert(this.value);
    });
});
```

As a side note, an ID shouldn't start with a number, even HTML5 spec allows it but still not supported by DOM node methods on all browsers or CSS.

Comment: Hey, i want to change the color of button on click permanently in the above code i.e. dynamically created buttons ..

Comment: @SumitChoudhary And then use relevant method